ASP.NET COREで、Cookie認証が維持できない
下記サイトを参考にして、ASP.NET COREにてCookie認証をおこなっています。
https://zenn.dev/microsoft/articles/aspnetcore-blazor-dotnet8-tryaddauth
ログイン画面（Login.razor）でログインし、Cookie認証された状態だと、PCを再起動してブラウザを開きなおしても、ログイン画面を経ずホーム画面（Home.razor）に遷移します。
しかし、Cookieの期限をセッションではなく下記コードのとおり7日間にしても、半日程度で認証が解除され、ブラウザで表示するとホーム画面ではなくログイン画面に戻ってしまいます。
その時も、開発者ツールで確認したところ、Cookieは期限通り保存されています。
上記サイトおよび下記コードはBlazor（Server）.NET8ですが、.NET6版でも、ASP.NET COREアプリでも試しましたが同様の症状です。
ブラウザはEdgeおよびChromeです。
Cookieの期限を複数日に設定するのは無理なのでしょうか？それとも、IISやブラウザの設定が必要なのでしょうか？
＜追記＞
下記サイトも参考にしました。
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-8.0
＜追記4/18＞
まだ検証中ですが、今回の症状はIISのアプリケーションプールの[ユーザー プロファイルの読み込み]が規定値falseのままだったため発生した可能性があります。
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/advanced?view=aspnetcore-8.0
[ユーザー プロファイルの読み込み]が規定値falseの場合、

データ保護キー リングがメモリに格納されている場合、アプリを再起動すると次のようになります。
すべての cookie ベースの認証トークンは無効になります。
ユーザーは、次回の要求時に再度サインインする必要があります。

これにより、定期的なリサイクルなど何からのタイミングでアプリが再起動して、ログイン状態が維持できなくなった可能性があります。
よって、これをtrueにして検証中です。
Program.csの一部抜粋（元コードから変更）
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;

        options.SlidingExpiration = true;//期限の半分を過ぎたCookieを持った状態でアクセスされた時に、有効期限を更新したCookieをアクセス元に渡す
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60*24*7);//Cookie認証 有効期限 (タイムアウト) の設定方法 https://sakutomo.com/asp-net-webapi-cookie-auth-timeout/
    });

Login.razorの一部抜粋（元コードから変更）
 var claims = new List<Claim>
     {
       new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "user"),
         new Claim("ShainId", "1"),
         new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"),
     };

 identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
         claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
 var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
     {
         IsPersistent = true, //cookie をブラウザー セッション間で永続化

         //サーバーアクセスによる認証時間を更新する
         AllowRefresh = true,
         // 認証の有効期間,認証cookieタイムアウト 
         ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60 * 24 * 7),

         //cookieの認証時間
         IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow
     };

 if (identity != null)
 {
     // ログイン成功！
     await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                new ClaimsPrincipal(identity)
                , authProperties);

     NavigationManager.NavigateTo(
         "",
         forceLoad: true
     );
 }
 else
 {
     // ログイン失敗
     ValidationMessageStore.Add(EditContext.Field(""), "ログインに失敗しました。");
 }

Home.razor（全部）
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h3>InteractiveServerPage</h3>

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <p>こんにちは @context.User.Identity!.Name さん。</p>

    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        @{
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo(
            "login",
            forceLoad: true
            );
        }
        <p>認証できなかった・・・</p>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>


参考にしている記事には「オレオレ ログイン機能」と書いてありますが、参考記事を書いた人の独自実装なのですか？　ASP.NET Core Identity の話であれば自分にも分かることはあると思いますが、個人の独自実装の話は考える気力が無いのでお聞きしています。

ちなみに質問者さんの言う「Cookie認証」が、ログインに成功すると Cookie に入れた認証チケットを受け取って、その後はブラウザから認証 Cookie が送信されることにより認証状態を維持する仕組みということであれば、ASP.NET Core Identity がそれです。

ASP.NET Core Identityを使わない方法です。
マイクロソフトの下記サイトに載っているものとほぼ同じ方法です。
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-8.0

「下記サイトも参考にしました」の通りにしても（有効期限は 1 週間にして）期待通りにならないのですか？

そうです。さらにこれに関連するサイトを調べ、いろいろ試しましたがいずれも同様の症状でした。

「永続化」したのであれば応答ヘッダの Set-Cookie に expires 属性が含まれているはずなので、まずその設定が期待通りか調べてはいかがですか？　そこが問題ないとして、クッキーの有効期限と認証チケットの有効期限が同じとは限らないので、それも調べてはいかがですか？　.NET Core 3.1 のASP.NET Core Identity と同じであればこのようにして調べることができます⇒ http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2020/10/31/judging-expiration-of-aspnet-core-authentication.aspx

ASP.NET Core クッキー認証の有効期限のデフォルト値は、14 日で、私の ASP.NET Core MVC の環境では、そのデフォルト値の複数日で機能しています。気になった点として、「半日程度で認証が解除され、ブラウザで表示するとホーム画面ではなくログイン画面に戻ってしまいます。」とありますが、この部分で認証されていることをどのように確認し、ログイン画面に遷移しているかの方法やコードを共有いただけないでしょうか？

Home.razorのコードを全て載せます。
これはほぼ、冒頭の参考サイト「.NET 8 の Blazor にオレオレ・・・」のInteractiveServerPage.razorと同じで、NotAuthorizedだとLogin.razorに遷移するようにしています。なお、遷移ではなくInteractiveServerPage.razorと同じにすると「認証されてませんよ？」と表示されるようになります。

＜追記4/18＞の件ですが、アプリが IIS でホストされている場合はレジストリに暗号キーにキーが保持されるので、後者の記事に書いてある「データ保護キー リングがメモリに格納されている場合、アプリを再起動すると次のようになります。すべての cookie ベースの認証トークンは無効になります」とはなりません。念のため、私のの回答のサンプリを IIS 10.0 にデプロイして検証しましたが、ワーカープロセスを再起動しても認証は維持されます。アプリケーションプールの設定などに何か普通でないことをしているのではないですか？

回答３
【追記２】
このスレッドの問題は、アプリケーションプールのリサイクルによってサーバーのデータ保護キーが失われるため、有効な認証クッキー・チケットがブラウザから送られてきても復号できず、結果リサイクル後はユーザー認証が維持できないということです。
以下はその解決策をまとめたものです。
ASP.NET Core アプリのデータ保護キーの管理は、Microsoft のドキュメント「ASP.NET Core でのデータ保護のキー管理と有効期間」によると、アプリにより運用環境が検出され、以下のいずれかになる:

アプリが Azure Apps でホストされている場合、キーは %HOME%ASP.NET_DataProtection-Keys フォルダーに保持されます。

ユーザー プロファイルを使用できる場合、キーは %LOCALAPPDATA%\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys フォルダーに保持されます。

アプリが IIS でホストされている場合、HKLM レジストリ内の、ワーカー プロセス アカウントにのみ ACL が設定されている特別なレジストリ キーにキーが保持されます。

これらの条件のいずれにも該当しない場合、キーは現在のプロセスの外部には保持されません。 プロセスがシャットダウンすると、生成されたキーはすべて失われます。


IIS でホストする場合は上の 2 と 3 が関係する。
2 つ目の条件
アプリを動かすとアプリケーションプール名で c:\users フォルダにフォルダが生成され「ユーザー プロファイルを使用できる」状態になる。2 で言う %LOCALAPPDATA% は c:\users\<アプリケーションプール名>\AppData\Local になる。（注: アプリケーションプール名の新規ユーザーが Windows に追加されるわけではなくてフォルダが生成されるだけ）
ただし、フォルダが作成されても、applicationHost.config の setProfileEnvironment 属性が true になってないとその下に ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys ホルダは作られず、データ保護キーも生成されない。
さらに、［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］は Ture に設定する必要がある。［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］を False に設定すると、データ保護キーが DataProtection-Keys フォルダに存在しても、リサイクル後は認証に失敗する。（メモリに保持したデータ保護キーを使うようです。この状態で 3 の条件のレジストリにもキーがある場合はどうなるか未検証です）
質問者さんの Windows Server 2019 の環境では setProfileEnvironment 属性が true になっていて、自分の Windows 10 Pro 環境では false になっていたところが、質問者さんの環境と自分の環境でリサイクル後もデータ保護キーが保持されるか否か（認証が継続されるか否か）の違いになったようです。
3 つ目の条件
アプリケーションプールを作成する際、 [.NET CLR バージョン] を [マネージド コードなし] （Microsoft の推奨）にするとデータ保護キーはレジストリに保持されることはない。上の 2 つ目の条件で ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys ホルダにデータ保護キーが保持されてない限り、リサイクル後はデータ保護キー失われ、認証が継続できない。
バグっぽいのでそのうち修正されるかもしれませんが、当面の解決策は［.NET CLR バージョン］を［.Net CLR バージョン v4.0.30319］にしておく、もしくは、一度ホストする ASP.NET Core アプリを［.Net CLR バージョン v4.0.30319］で動かした後で、 [マネージド コードなし] に設定することだと思います。
3 の条件に頼らないで、確実に 2 の条件を満足するように設定するのが本筋かもしれません。

以下は上の【追記２】にたどり着くまでの途中過程・紆余曲折です。間違っているわけではないので削除せず載せておきますが、上の【追記２】だけ読んでいただいた方が良さそうです。
【訂正】
先に "アプリケーションプールを新規作成する際に［.NET CLR バージョン］を［マネージド コードなし］に設定しても、［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］をデフォルトの Ture のままとしておけばリサイクルで問題が出ることは無かったです" と書きましたが、間違ってました。やはりリサイクルで暗号キーが失われます。
【訂正２】
自分の Windows 10 Pro PC の applicationHost.congif の setProfileEnvironment の設定を調べたところ false になってました。Microsoft のドキュメント「ASP.NET Core でのデータ保護のキー管理と有効期間」に "一部のシナリオ (たとえば、Windows OS) では、setProfileEnvironment は false に設定されます" に書いてありますがその通りのようです。setProfileEnvironment の設定を ture にして検証してみた結果、質問者さんのケースと同様に［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］の設定が true / false で違いがありました。以下、その結果を踏まえて訂正しておきます。
今更ながらですが、自分の開発マシンの Windows 10 のローカル IIS 10.0 で質問者さんの回答の「＜追記＞4/22」の件を検証してみました。検証結果を以下にまとめて書いておきます。
(1) 新規作成時に［.NET CLR バージョン］が［v4.0］のときは問題なし。［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］は Ture でも False でも影響なし。これは自分が先の回答で書いたことです。
(2) 新規作成時に［.NET CLR バージョン］を［マネージド コードなし］に設定し、［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］を False に設定 (デフォルトは Ture) するとリサイクルで暗号キーは失われる。
その後［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］を True に設定しても効果なく、やはりリサイクルで暗号キーは失われる。（質問者さんのケースと違いますか？）
質問者さんが書いた通り、［.NET CLR バージョン］を［マネージド コードなし］から［v4.0］に設定し、その後すぐ［マネージド コードなし］に戻すという操作で暗号キーはリサイクル後も保持されるようになり、問題はなくなる。
(3) 新規作成時に［.NET CLR バージョン］を［マネージド コードなし］に設定し、［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］はデフォルトの Ture のままとしてアプリケーションプールを作れば問題なし。リサイクルで暗号キーが失われることはない。その後［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］を False に変更しても問題なし。<= このアプリケーションプールは、先に［.NET CLR バージョン］が［v4.0］で作ったアプリケーションプールを削除して同じ名前で作り直したもので、その時できた暗号キー保存用のレジストリが、アプリケーションプールを削除しても同じ名前で残っていて、それゆえ、リサイクルしても問題ないという結果になったようです。
(4) 以前作ったアプリケーションプールと異なる名前で、［.NET CLR バージョン］を［マネージド コードなし］に設定し、［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］はデフォルトの Ture のままとしてアプリケーションプールを新規作成。結果、上の (2) と同様にリサイクルでリサイクルで暗号キーは失われる。<= これは自分の Windows 10 Pre PC の applicationHost.congif の setProfileEnvironment の設定が false になっていたことによるものでした。setProfileEnvironment の設定を true にすると［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］の影響がありました。【追記２】にまとめたのでそちらを見てください。
要するに、アプリケーションプールの新規作成時に［.NET CLR バージョン］を［マネージド コードなし］にすると暗号キーがレジストリに保存されず、リサイクルで失われ、ブラウザから有効な認証クッキー/チケットが送られてきても認証に失敗するという結果になりました。

【追記】
下のコメント欄で「ご参考までに、自分の Windows 10 PC の %LOCALAPPDATA%\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys の内容を上の回答欄に追記しておきます」と書いた件です。質問者さんの環境で［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］を true にするとこれを読みに行くのではないかと想像してます。

複数ありますが、最後のものを除いては有効期限が切れてます。Microsoft のドキュメント「ASP.NET Core でのデータ保護のキー管理と有効期間」に書いてある通り、キーの有効期間は既定で 90 日で、キーの有効期限が切れると、アプリによって自動的に新しいキーが生成されるそうです。
xml ファイルなのでメモ帳で開いて見ることができます。上の画像の最後のものの内容は以下の通りです。
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<key id="ee2431c3-ddab-4b2f-8b26-72db14124719" version="1">
  <creationDate>2024-02-02T01:06:27.1954928Z</creationDate>
  <activationDate>2024-02-02T01:06:26.9325483Z</activationDate>
  <expirationDate>2024-05-02T01:06:26.9325483Z</expirationDate>
  <descriptor deserializerType="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.ConfigurationModel.AuthenticatedEncryptorDescriptorDeserializer, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60">
    <descriptor>
      <encryption algorithm="AES_256_CBC" />
      <validation algorithm="HMACSHA256" />
      <encryptedSecret decryptorType="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" xmlns="http://schemas.asp.net/2015/03/dataProtection">
        <encryptedKey xmlns="">
          <!-- This key is encrypted with Windows DPAPI. -->
          <value>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</value>
        </encryptedKey>
      </encryptedSecret>
    </descriptor>
  </descriptor>
</key>


調査ありがとうございます。［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］Trueにすれば［.NET CLR バージョン］が最初から［マネージド コードなし］でも暗号キーが失われず認証が維持されることは何度も検証済みであり、ネット情報の多くはこの方法を勧めています。
今回改めて、複数のサーバー・複数のアプリでアプリケーションプールを作り直して試してみましたが同様でした。逆にうっかり［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］をTrueにし忘れたアプリは、Cookie認証が維持できませんでした。

WebSurferさんは『［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］はデフォルトの True のまま』と書いておられますが、これはWindows10のIISだからではないでしょうか？私のWindows11でもデフォルトはTrueですが、私のWindowsServer2019は4台ともデフォルトはFalseです。マイクロソフトのサイトでも「デフォルトはFalse」と明確に書いてないものの、Falseが既定値であると推測するに足る書き方がされていると思います。検証してませんが、デフォルトがTrueの場合は、あえてFalseにして再度Trueにしないと、暗号キーが保存されないのかもしれません。

自分の開発マシンの Windows 10 のローカル IIS 10.0 では確かに上に述べたようになりますが（詳しくは自分のブログの記事 http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2024/04/25/data-protection-key-management-in-aspnet-core.aspx に書いたので興味があれば見てください）、Windows Server の IIS では違うと言われると、自分は Windows Server で検証できる環境を持ってないので何とも言えません。

Microsoft のドキュメント「ASP.NET Core でのデータ保護のキー管理と有効期間」によると、アプリにより運用環境が検出され、"2. ユーザー プロファイルを使用できる場合、キーは %LOCALAPPDATA%\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys フォルダーに保持されます" とのことです。ApplicationPoolIdentity にユーザープロファイルは無いのでそれは該当しないと思っています。しかし、質問者さんのケースでは Windows Server にユーザー（ユーザープロファイルを持つ）を追加してそれをアプリケーションプール ID に設定していたから、［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］の true / false が影響しているのではないかと想像してますが、違いますか？

ちなみにですが、Visual Studio を使って ASP.NET Core アプリを起動すると IIS Express が動きますが、その時の IIS Express のワーカープロセスのアカウントは Visual Studio を起動したユーザーのアカウントになり、それはユーザープロファイルを持っています。なので、キーは %LOCALAPPDATA%\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys フォルダーに保持されます。

ご参考までに、自分の Windows 10 PC の %LOCALAPPDATA%\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys の内容を上の回答欄に追記しておきます。

「質問者さんのケースでは Windows Server にユーザー（ユーザープロファイルを持つ）を追加してそれをアプリケーションプール ID に設定していたから」←違います。調べてみたら全く逆でした。ApplicationPoolIdentityのままです。その状態で［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］Trueにしてアプリを実行すると、C:\Usersフォルダに自動的にアプリケーションプール名のユーザーが作られ、そこにキーが保存されました。

なお、開発はローカル（Windows11のVisualStudio）でおこなっており、実行はWindowsServer2019でおこなっています。

自分の Windows 10 PC  の IIS 10.0 でも c:\users フォルダにアプリケーションプール名のフォルダは作られてました。でも、その下の \AppData\Local フォルダには ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys フォルダはなくキーもありません。［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］が true でもです。その違いが影響していたようですね。

自分の Windows 10 Pro PC の applicationHost.congif の setProfileEnvironment の設定を調べたところ false になってました。Microsoft のドキュメント「ASP.NET Core でのデータ保護のキー管理と有効期間」に "一部のシナリオ (たとえば、Windows OS) では、setProfileEnvironment は false に設定されます" に書いてありますがその通りのようです。多分これが結果の違いになったと思います。後で検証してみます。

setProfileEnvironment の設定を ture にして検証してみた結果、質問者さんのケースと同様に［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］の設定が true / false で違いがありました。その結果を踏まえて上の回答を訂正しておきます。

回答１
注: この回答は「回答３」の【追記２】にたどり着くまでの途中過程・紆余曲折です。間違っているわけではないので削除せず載せておきますが、「回答３」の【追記２】だけ読んでいただいた方が良さそうです。

質問欄下の私のコメント、

「下記サイトも参考にしました」の通りにしても（有効期限は 1 週間にして）期待通りにならないのですか？

に対する答えが、

そうです。さらにこれに関連するサイトを調べ、いろいろ試しましたがいずれも同様の症状でした。

とのことだったので、

下記サイトも参考にしました。
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-8.0

のリンク先のサンプルコードをダウンロードして、コメントに書いた以下の件を試してみました。

「永続化」したのであれば応答ヘッダの Set-Cookie に expires 属性が含まれているはずなので、まずその設定が期待通りか調べてはいかがですか？　そこが問題ないとして、クッキーの有効期限と認証チケットの有効期限が同じとは限らないので、それも調べてはいかがですか？

結果は以下のようになります。
応答ヘッダの expires 属性

認証チケットの有効期限

半日経つとどうなるかはまだ試してませんが、たぶん、上の結果から、半日経っても有効な認証クッキー・チケットは送られてくるはずです。
なので、

半日程度で認証が解除され、ブラウザで表示するとホーム画面ではなくログイン画面に戻ってしまいます。

というのは質問者さんのやり方の問題とか、質問者さんの Blazor アプリとの相性とか、「オレオレ ログイン機能」の問題ではなかろうかと思います。
参考までにどのようにして検証したかを以下に書いておきます。
.NET 6.0 のサンプルプロジェクトを GitHub からダウンロードして Windows 10 の Visual Studio 2022 17.9.6 で開き、以下の点のみ手を加えました。
(1) 永続化（認証クッキーを HDD/SSD に保存）するため既存の Login.cshtml.cs の IsPersistent = true, のコメントアウトを解除
(2) 認証チケットの有効期限を 1 週間に設定するため Program.cs の .AddCookie のオプションで有効期限を指定
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60 * 24 * 7);
});

(3) 暗号化されている認証チケットを復号し、認証チケットの有効期限の日時を取得するページ AuthExpireCheck を追加。
AuthExpireCheck.cshtml.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace CookieSample.Pages
{
    public class AuthExpireCheckModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly CookieAuthenticationOptions _options;

        public AuthExpireCheckModel(IOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions> options)
        {
            _options = options.Value;
        }

        public string Message { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        // デフォルトの Cookie 名は ASP.NET Core Identity の .AspNetCore.Identity.Application
            // とは異なり以下のようになっていた
            string cookie = Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Cookies"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie))
            {
                IDataProtectionProvider provider = _options.DataProtectionProvider;
                IDataProtector protector = provider.CreateProtector(
                    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware",
                    "Cookies",    // Cookie 名 .AspNetCore.Cookies から .AspNetCore. を削除
                    "v2");

                // 認証クッキーから暗号化された認証チケットを復号
                TicketDataFormat format = new TicketDataFormat(protector);
                AuthenticationTicket authTicket = format.Unprotect(cookie);

                // ユーザー名を取得
                ClaimsPrincipal principal = authTicket.Principal;
                IIdentity identity = principal.Identity;
                string userName = identity.Name;

                // 認証チケットの有効期限の日時を取得
                AuthenticationProperties property = authTicket.Properties;
                DateTimeOffset? expiersUrc = property.ExpiresUtc;

                // ExpiresUtc と現在の時刻を比較して期限切れか否かを判定
                if (expiersUrc.Value < DateTimeOffset.UtcNow)
                {
                    Message = $"{userName} さん、認証チケットの有効期限 {expiersUrc.Value} が切れています。";
                }
                else
                {
                    Message = $"{userName} さん、認証チケットは有効期限 {expiersUrc.Value} 内です。";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Message = "認証クッキーがサーバーに送信されてきていません。";
            }
        }
    }
}


詳細に教えて頂き、ありがとうございます。検証してみます。

なぜASP.NET Core Identity を使わないのですか？ 作ろうとしているのは .NET 8.0 の Blazor Web App ですよね。であれば、Visual Studio でプロジェクトを作成する際、「認証の種類」に 「個別のアカウント」を選んでプロジェクトを生成すれば何の苦も無く Cookie ベースの認証システムが実装されます。「下記サイトも参考にしました」は ASP.NET Core Identity から Cookie 認証のみ抜き出した簡易版です。簡易版だからと言って初学者の方にも簡単に作れるわけではありません。

ご助言ありがとうございます。上記ご回答のコードをサーバーのIISにデプロイしたところ、正常に認証チケット有効期限が表示されました。数時間経っても維持できているか確認する予定です。

「永続化」したのであれば応答ヘッダの Set-Cookie に expires 属性が含まれているはず・・・と書きましたけどそちらは確認したのですか？　それが確認できていて、認証チケットの有効期限が expires 属性のそれと同じなら、ユーザーがブラウザの Cookie を消去したり、ログアウトしたり（ログアウトすると認証クッキーは削除される）しない限り結果は明らか（期限内であれば有効な認証クッキー/チケットはブラウザからサーバーに間違いなく送られてくる）ということは理解されてますか？

なぜASP.NET Core Identity を使わないのですか？ ・・・にも答えてもらえませんか

失礼しました。応答ヘッダの Set-Cookie にはexpires 属性が含まれていて、認証チケットの有効期限と同じでした。期限内であれば有効な認証クッキー/チケットはブラウザからサーバーに間違いなく送られてくることは理解しています。

ご回答にあるサンプルプロジェクトやBlazorアプリで試しましたが、認証チケットの有効期限が expires 属性のそれと同じにかかわらず、ログイン状態を維持できませんでした。IISの設定に問題があるかもしれないので、試しているところです。

なぜASP.NET Core Identity を使わないのか。色々あるので一言で説明するのは難しいですが、結論を言えば、経営者兼社内SEリーダーである私の、リスクとコストを承知のうえでの決断です。

「IISの設定に問題があるかもしれない」<= IIS は関係ないです。IIS からクライアントの PC の HDD/SSD に保存されているクッキーを一方的に削除するということは、IIS をどう設定しようと、100% 不可能ですから。クライアントの PC にあるクッキーを削除するにはどういう操作が必要か理解されているでしょうか？

ASP.NET Core Identity を使わない理由が技術的な問題によるものであれば（例えば、email confirmation は不要だが、RCL で提供されている機能ををいじれないとか）、ASP.NET Core Identity を使う方が間違いなくリスクとコストは低いと思いますけど？　技術的な問題であれば、それを解決する方向でも検討した方がいいと思いますがいかがですか。

ちなみに、上に紹介した検証に使ったアプリですが、昨日 PC をシャットダウン後、今日再度 PC を立ち上げてアプリを起動して試してみましたが、約 18 時間後も認証クッキーはブラウザから送信され、認証状態は継続します。当たり前ですが

「IISの設定に問題があるかもしれない」件について、Cookie自体が時間がたつと削除されるわけではなく、Cookieがあってもログイン状態を維持できなくなります。BlazorアプリやASP.net Coreアプリでは、IISアプリケーションプールの[ユーザープロファイルの読み込み]をtrueにするとなぜか、ログイン状態を維持できるようになります。サンプルプロジェクトもその設定にして調査中です。

ASP.NET Core Identityを使わない理由を説明するとややこしくなるのでする気はないし、何より今のやり方を探求し成し遂げたいと思っています。経営者がリスクとコストが上がっても今の方法を選択する（その責任を負う）と言えば、それ以上のことは無いのではないのでしょうか？

「経営者がリスクとコストが上がっても今の方法を選択する（その責任を負う）と言えば、それ以上のことは無いのではないのでしょうか？」=> ここのようなサイトは技術者同士の情報交換の場でもあると思っているのですが？　業務上の秘密とかの事情があれば話は別ですが、純技術的なことなら質問者さんの方からも情報提供していただきたいのですが。

「IISアプリケーションプールの[ユーザープロファイルの読み込み]をtrueにするとなぜか、ログイン状態を維持できるようになります」⇒ それは ASP.NET Core のクッキー認証の原理的に関係ないです。何らかの関係があるとすると、想像を膨らませるとですが、ユーザー情報のストアに LocalDB を運用環境でも使っていて (そもそも、そういうことはしてはいけないのですが)、LocalDB はユーザープロファイルが無いと動かないので、[ユーザープロファイルの読み込み]を true にして対応したとかです。でも、そうだとすると最初から動かないし、「下記サイトも参考にしました」のサンプルはそういう問題とは全く関係ないし、不可解ではありますが。なんか迷走してるような気がします。

迷走はしてないと思います。
最初に書いたとおり、Cookie認証で認証状態が維持できずログイン画面に戻ってしまうことが問題でした。
それでもCookieは期限通り保存されていました。（つまり削除されません。）
厳密な原因は分かりませんが、[ユーザー プロファイルの読み込み]をTrueにすることで当該の問題は解決したので、クローズとします。

ASP.NET Core Identityを使わない理由を説明するのが難しい、コストをかけてでも使わない方法を探求したい、責任を負ってでも使わないと決断したと何度も伝えているのに、その思いを取るに足りないことのように、ASP.NET Core Identityを使う方が間違いなくリスクとコストは低いなどと一方的に勧め、技術不足と勝手に推測しつつ聞いてくるのはどうなのでしょう。
だいたい「個人の独自実装の話は考える気力が無い」と仰ったのなら、あえて独自実装にこだわりたい私に助言をする必要ないのでは？
技術者同士の情報交換の場とのことですが、そもそもコミュニケーションの前提が壊れていると思います。

独自実装を考える気力はありませんが、「下記サイトも参考にしました。 https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-8.0」でも同じと言うところに興味を引かれてたのです。その基本的なところをクリアにしないと話にならないということで、コミュニケーションの前提は崩れていないはずです。

上で紹介したアプリを自分の開発マシンのローカル IIS 10.0 にデプロイして検証しました。[ユーザープロファイルの読み込み] の設定は上にコメントに書いた通り関係ないことが確認できました。詳しくは別の回答に書きましたので見てください。

本文にも追記しましたが問題解決しました。
検証の結果、下記の方法でCookie認証（ログイン状態）がCookie有効期限まで維持できるようになりました。
IISのアプリケーションプールの[ユーザー プロファイルの読み込み]をTrueにするとともに、applicationHost.configファイルのsetProfileEnvironment属性もTrue（規定値）にする。
以下、私が調べた限りの、原因と思われることを書きます。
今回の症状とともに、サーバーのイベントビューアで下記の例外が発生していました。

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.

これは調べていくと、偽造防止トークンが復号できないのは、データ保護キーが正しく保存されていないことが原因のようでした。
（それは厳密には、正しい権限が与えられていないからかもしれません。）
Stack Overflow海外版などでも同様の症状が数々報告されており、解決法はやはり[ユーザー プロファイルの読み込み]をTrueにすることでした。
マイクロソフトの下記サイトにもデータ保護キーの管理として同様の方法が載っていました。
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/default-settings?view=aspnetcore-8.0
また下記サイトには、データ保護を構成しない場合、既定でキーはメモリ内に保持され、アプリが再起動すると破棄されることが載っていました。
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/advanced?view=aspnetcore-8.0

データ保護を構成しない場合、既定でキーはメモリ内に保持され、アプリが再起動すると破棄されます。
データ保護キーリングがメモリに格納されている場合、アプリを再起動すると次のようになります。
すべての cookie ベースの認証トークンは無効になります。
ユーザーは、次回の要求時に再度サインインする必要があります。

以上により、定期的なリサイクルなど何からのタイミングでアプリが再起動して、ログイン状態が維持できなくなっていたと思われます。
これを、[ユーザー プロファイルの読み込み]をTrueにし、setProfileEnvironment属性もTrue（規定値）にすることで、キーがメモリーではなくファイルに保存されるようになるため、アプリが再起動しても認証状態が維持されるようになりました。
以上により、今回の問題は解決しました。
＜追記＞4/22
WebSurferさんの新たな投稿に基づき、さらに調査・検証したところ、WebSurferさんのおかげでもっと簡単な解決法が見つかりました。
アプリケーションプールの[.NetCLRバージョン]を一瞬でも「v4.0」にすれば、その後「マネージドコードなし」に変更しても、Cookie認証状態が有効期限通り維持できるようになりました。
以下、根拠や経緯を説明します。
WebSurferさんの投稿内にある画像では、アプリケーションプールの[.NetCLRバージョン]が「v4.0」になっていますが、ASP.NET Coreの場合、ここを「マネージドコードなし」にすることが推奨されています。（必須ではない）
よって私はいつもここを「マネージドコードなし」にしていました。
しかし、[.NetCLRバージョン]が「マネージドコードなし」かつ［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］がFalseの場合、当初の問題であったCookie認証状態が維持できない現象が起きていました。
これは、当社のサーバー4台（それぞれ設置場所・時期・導入担当者が異なる）で試しましたが同様でした。
今回、上記の解決法を4台のサーバーでそれぞれ5回以上試したところ、いずれも[.NetCLRバージョン]を一瞬でも「v4.0」にすれば維持できました。
また、[.NetCLRバージョン]を一瞬でも「v4.0」にしない場合は、［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］をTrueにした間だけ、維持できました。（Falseに戻すと維持できなくなる。）
私の考察は下記のとおりです。
マイクロソフトのサイト
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/advanced?view=aspnetcore-8.0#data-protection
に下記のとおり書いてあります。

キーリングを保持するために IIS でのデータ保護を構成するには、次のいずれかの方法を使用する必要があります。
・データ保護のレジストリ キーを作成する
　データ保護の PowerShell スクリプト Provision-AutoGenKeys.ps1・・・レジストリ キーが作成されます。
・ユーザー プロファイルを読み込むための IIS アプリケーション プールを構成する

後者の方法は［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］をTrueにすることですが、
前者の方法はスクリプトを実行することが必要だったのかもしれませんが、私はそれをしていませんでした。
しかし今回、[.NetCLRバージョン]を「v4.0」にすることで、レジストリキーが出来たのではないかと推測します。
いずれにしても、当社のサーバー4台では当初、データ保護キーがレジストリにもファイルにも保存されず、よってCookie認証状態が維持出来なかったのだと推測します。
この件を調査するためにネットで調べたところ、過去のバージョンではバグだったと書いてあったり、それがASP.NET Coreの既定の仕様だと書いてあったり色々でしたが、［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］をTrueにすることが一番多く書かれていた解決法でした。
以下、それらのサイトURLを列挙します。（今回の事例と関係ないものも含まれている可能性があります。）
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72627292/data-protection-keys-not-persisted-on-newer-os
https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/issues/102
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40783170/neither-user-profile-nor-hklm-registry-available-using-an-ephemeral-key-reposit
https://cypressnorth.com/web-programming-and-development/solved-using-memory-repository-keys-will-not-persisted-storage-asp-net-core-iis/
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/using-an-inmemory-repositoryquot-and-quotno-xml-encryptor-configured

参考にしている前者の記事に「3. アプリが IIS でホストされている場合、HKLM レジストリ内の、ワーカー プロセス アカウントにのみ ACL が設定されている特別なレジストリ キーにキーが保持されます。」と書いてある通りメモリに暗号キーが保持されるわけではないので、後者の記事に書いてある「データ保護を構成しない場合、既定でキーはメモリ内に保持され、アプリが再起動すると破棄されます。」とはなりません。念のため、上の回答のサンプリを IIS 10.0 にデプロイして検証しましたが、ワーカープロセスを再起動しても認証は維持されます。アプリケーションプールの設定などに何か普通でないことをしているのではないですか？

情報提供をありがとうございます。どういう仕組みで [.NetCLRバージョン] を一瞬でも「v4.0」にすれば解決するのか理解し難いですが、「マネージドコードなし」にするとそういう問題があるということはおぼえておきます。

今更ながらですが、自分の開発マシンの Windows 10 のローカル IIS 10.0 で上の質問者さんの回答の「＜追記＞4/22」の件を検証してみました。後でまとめて検証結果を回答欄に書いておきます。肝心なことだけ書くと、アプリケーションプールを新規作成する際に［.NET CLR バージョン］を［マネージド コードなし］に設定しても、［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］をデフォルトの Ture のままとしておけばリサイクルで問題が出ることは無かったです。（だから巷では問題が顕著化しなかったように思われます。デフォルトで True なのに質問者さんがわざわざ False に設定したのは何故ですか？）

上のコメントで "アプリケーションプールを新規作成する際に［.NET CLR バージョン］を［マネージド コードなし］に設定しても、［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］をデフォルトの Ture のままとしておけばリサイクルで問題が出ることは無かったです。" と書きましたが、間違ってました。その場合もやはりリサイクルで暗号キーが失われます。詳しくは回答欄に書きます。

回答２
注: この回答は「回答３」の【追記２】にたどり着くまでの途中過程・紆余曲折です。間違っているわけではないので削除せず載せておきますが、「回答３」の【追記２】だけ読んでいただいた方が良さそうです。


データ保護キー リングがメモリに格納されている場合、アプリを再起動すると次のようになります。すべての cookie ベースの認証トークンは無効になります

Microsoft の記事 https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/default-settings?view=aspnetcore-8.0 (質問者さんが紹介した記事の日本語版）に、


アプリが IIS でホストされている場合、HKLM レジストリ内の、ワーカー プロセス アカウントにのみ ACL が設定されている特別なレジストリ キーにキーが保持されます。


と書いてある通りメモリに暗号キーが保持されるわけではないので、アプリを再起動すると暗号キーが失われるということはありません。なので「すべての cookie ベースの認証トークンは無効になります」ということもありません。
念のため、私の回答で書いたサンプルを自分の開発マシンのローカル IIS 10.0 にデプロイして検証しましたが、ワーカープロセスを再起動しても認証は維持されます。
どのように検証したかを以下に書いておきます。
(1) C:\WebSites2019 というフォルダ下に AspNetCoreCookieAuth という名前のフォルダを作成。
(2) IIS Manager を起動して AspNetCoreCookieAuth という名前でアプリケーションプールを新たに作成。質問者さんのケースに合わせて［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］を False に設定 (デフォルトは Ture)。その他はデフォルトのまま。

(3) IIS Manager のサイトの追加で、上記 (1) のフォルダをサイトに設定。サイト名は AspNetCoreCookieAuth とし、アプリケーションプールは上記 (2) で新たに作成したものを設定。サイトバインド設定は、種類: http, IP アドレス: 未使用の IP アドレスすべて, ポート: 80, ホスト名: www.aspnetcorecookieauth.com とした。


(4) hosts ファイルに 127.0.0.1 www.aspnetcorecookieauth.com を追加。
(5) Microsoft のチュートリアル「IIS に ASP.NET Core アプリを発行する」の「アプリを発行および配置する」セクションに従って、上のステップで作成した C:\WebSites2019\AspNetCoreCookieAuth フォルダにプロジェクトを発行。インプロセスホスティングになります (Microsoft 推奨)。

(6) 実行結果

(7) 一旦ブラウザを閉じて、再度立ち上げ http://www.aspnetcorecookieauth.com を要求。認証は維持される。（Set-Cookie の expires 属性は有効に機能している）
(8) IIS Manager で AspNetCoreCookieAuth をリサイクル後、http://www.aspnetcorecookieauth.com を要求しても認証は維持される。（リサイクルで暗号キーが失われることはない）
(9) 念のため PC をシャットダウンして再起動してから試しても同様に認証は維持される。（PC シャットダウンでも暗号キーが失われることはない）

質問者さんのケースで［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］を Ture に設定（デフォルトで True ですが）したら解決したという理由は分かりませんが、アプリケーションプールの設定などに何か普通でないことをしているとか、Web ファームになっているとか、いろいろ試しているうちに解決して実は［ユーザープロファイルの読み込み］は原因ではなかったとかはないですか？


その時も、開発者ツールで確認したところ、Cookieは期限通り保存されています。

まず、AuthenticationProperties で設定した内容が正しくクッキーに反映されていることを確認ください。ブラウザー開発ツールでは設定内容は確認できないためサーバーサイドで確認する必要があります。
サーバーサイドでのクッキー内認証チケット設定の確認方法
Program.cs の AddCookie に以下のようにコードを追加し、各設定を確認できます。
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options => 
    {
        // サーバーサイドでの各設定

        options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnValidatePrincipal = context =>
            {
                // Visual Studio 出力に各種設定を出力                            
                Debug.WriteLine($"context.Principal.Identity.Name: {context.Principal?.Identity?.Name}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"context.Properties.AllowRefresh: {context.Properties.AllowRefresh}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"context.Properties.IsPersistent: {context.Properties.IsPersistent}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"context.Properties.IssuedUtc: {context.Properties.IssuedUtc}");
                Debug.WriteLine($"context.Properties.ExpiresUtc: {context.Properties.ExpiresUtc}");

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });

AuthenticationProperties に設定した IsPersistent, ExpiresUtc が正しく設定されていれば、その設定に基づいた振る舞いになるはずです。

ありがとうございます。ローカルでデバッグ実行したところ、正しく設定されていました。サーバー上でアプリを実行して正しく設定されるか、確認してみます。

サーバーサイドでも正しく設定されていることが確認できました。ありがとうございます。また、IISの設定を少し変えたことで、今のところログイン状態が維持できています。あとはそのIISの設定変更が良いことなのかどうかを確認しているところです。
